# Finding a distribution to fit truncated data

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting, distributions

I have certain experimental data with the following PDF.

[image: histogram]

As you may note the data does not take values lower than 0.

Using `FindDistribution` I get the following fit:

[image: distribution fit]

Is there any good way to fit this kind of "truncated" data with any of the built in distributions?

I tried to use some non negative distributions in Target distributions:

```
 TargetFunctions -> {LogNormalDistribution, NormalDistribution, 
  GammaDistribution, ChiSquareDistribution, HalfNormalDistribution, 
  ExponentialDistribution, InverseGaussianDistribution}
```

But didn't get better results.

The data for the Histogram using `HistogramList` is the following:

```
{{0., 0.005, 0.01, 0.015, 0.02, 0.025, 0.03, 0.035, 0.04, 0.045, 0.05,
   0.055, 0.06, 0.065, 0.07, 0.075, 0.08, 0.085, 0.09, 0.095, 0.1, 
  0.105, 0.11, 0.115, 0.12, 0.125, 0.13, 0.135, 0.14, 0.145, 0.15, 
  0.155, 0.16, 0.165, 0.17, 0.175, 0.18, 0.185, 0.19, 0.195, 0.2, 
  0.205, 0.21, 0.215, 0.22, 0.225, 0.23, 0.235, 0.24, 0.245, 0.25, 
  0.255, 0.26, 0.265, 0.27, 0.275, 0.28, 0.285, 0.29, 0.295, 0.3, 
  0.305, 0.31, 0.315, 0.32, 0.325, 0.33, 0.335, 0.34}, {8.35598, 
  8.30599, 6.7505, 6.00847, 5.41484, 4.65615, 3.66651, 3.48715, 
  3.47286, 3.45858, 3.66571, 3.7673, 3.7546, 3.71889, 3.66492, 
  3.69746, 4.05458, 4.31727, 3.91094, 4.22997, 4.57044, 5.01803, 
  4.90375, 4.78233, 4.99502, 4.71249, 4.45139, 4.43949, 4.48314, 
  4.47123, 4.37917, 4.46488, 4.55615, 4.44187, 4.29664, 3.98316, 
  3.95221, 3.73317, 3.01257, 2.63084, 2.44751, 2.25228, 2.25149, 
  2.01023, 2.04991, 1.86659, 1.69675, 1.44597, 1.16582, 1.02694, 
  0.637274, 0.569023, 0.463472, 0.367444, 0.295225, 0.233323, 
  0.192849, 0.126979, 0.0880914, 0.0253957, 0.0261893, 0.0047617, 
  0.0198404, 0.0222213, 0.0253957, 0.0388872, 0.0111106, 0.00238085}}
```

Yo can see the data (around 250.00 points) in the following link:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxzVmMJwPgcNem5xZXFfSnJiQVE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you provide the input data you used and put it e.g. on pastebin?

Comment: @halirutan The original data has around 250.000 values. I'll make it available trough mi google drive

Comment: Why does your data contain a lot of negative values? Assuming I have loaded your csv file into `data` can you please add how you achieved your first histogram?

Comment: @halirutan I'm sorry, I'll correct the file. The actual data is just the square of each value.

Comment: After some sleep, I reworked my answer to include all 4 peaks in your original data. Please see my edits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you said in the comments, the data for your histograms did contain negatives and you squared all of them. I suggest to consider looking at your values before you square them

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Although I have no insight into the underlying process that created the data, one could assume that you have 4 mixed normal distributions here.
It seem the left peak is again divide into two distributions.
Let us use this for a start and define a mixture distribution:

```
dist = MixtureDistribution[{a, b, c, 
   d}, {NormalDistribution[μ1, σ1], 
   NormalDistribution[μ2, σ2], 
   NormalDistribution[μ3, σ3], 
   NormalDistribution[μ4, σ4]}]
```

Now we can estimate the parameters by using `FindDistributionParameters`. I have roughly estimated the initial the initial conditions by just looking where the peaks are, and how high and wide they are:

```
sol = 
 FindDistributionParameters[data, 
  dist, {{a, 
    1}, {μ1, -.4}, {σ1, .1}, {b, .3}, {μ2, .1}, {\
σ2, .05}, {c, .5}, {μ3, .4}, {σ3, .1}, {d, .4}, {\
μ4, -.2}, {σ4, .1}}]
(* {a -> 0.376702, b -> 0.125485, c -> 0.275036, 
 d -> 0.222777, μ1 -> -0.395739, σ1 -> 0.0586256, μ2 ->
   0.103749, σ2 -> 0.0496838, μ3 -> 0.337538, σ3 -> 
  0.0866439, μ4 -> -0.217508, σ4 -> 0.0911891} *)
```

With 250.000 data values, Mathematica has no problem finding a good fit. Looking at it reveals:

```
pdf1 = PDF[dist, x] /. sol;

Show[
 Histogram[data, {0.03}, "PDF"],
 Plot[PDF[dist, x] /. sol, {x, -.6, .6}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now, since you squared all your values, we need to transform the found mixture distribution as well and you will end up with a distribution that has only values for positive x and fits your data very nicely:

```
pdf = PDF[TransformedDistribution[u^2, u \[Distributed] dist], x] /. sol;
Show[
 Histogram[data^2, {0.007}, "PDF"],
 Plot[pdf, {x, 0, .6}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 9):

Because your distribution is (at least) bimodal and because the probability density is greater than zero at zero, you might consider using nonparametric density estimation rather than maybe a poor approximation with a mixture of a small number of distributions.  (However, if it works with a mixture distribution, then that's great.)

You've got lots and lots of data and you don't need to force a description with a mixture of standard distributions.

Many times just using `SmoothKernelDistribution` on the data gets you everything you need.  In this case because the density is definitely not zero at the border of zero, one needs to do a bit of (commonly used) trickery but one still gets a legitimate and appropriate estimate of the probability density.  (See 
[Silverman, Page 20](https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/March02/Silverman/paper.pdf)).

First one creates a dataset that includes a reflection of the data:

```
data2 = Flatten[{data, -data}];
```

Then the `SmoothKernelDistribution` function is used followed by truncating the resulting distribution to be between zero and $\infty$.

```
skd2 = SmoothKernelDistribution[data2];
skd = TruncatedDistribution[{0, ∞}, skd2];
```

One then has access to the functions associated with a probability distribution:  PDF, CDF, Expectation, etc.

```
Plot[PDF[skd, x], {x, 0, 0.4}]
```

[image: Nonparametric density estimate]

To repeat:  when you've got lots of data you are not restricted to standard distributions.  Really.

Comment: Would it be possible to use the `TransformedDistribution` function on a distribution found by `SmoothKernelDistribution`? Or has this disadvantages?

Comment: Good idea.  It would be nice if that worked and it would be more straightforward than what I did.  But with this data I just get the command echoed back when attempting to use `PDF` and `CDF` with that transformed distribution.  However, `Expectation` seems to work with it.

Comment: @JimBaldwin I found that     `SmoothKernelDistribution[ data, Automatic, {"Bounded", {0, [Infinity]}, "Gaussian"}]`     also works and seem to make a better fit. Thanks for pointing out this solution.

Comment: The "Bounded" option works great.  Thanks for pointing that out.  One doesn't need to go through the "data reflection" trick that I included.  But I would have to believe that's what's done behind the curtain.  The fits seem similar to me but using the "Bounded" option does result in smaller bandwidths which means a "bumpier" curve.

Comment: This seems very relevant:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88908/documentation-for-the-bounded-option-of-smoothkerneldistribution.

Comment: And another:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15547/representative-smooth-kernel-distribution-from-truncated-distribution/15549#15549.

Comment: @halirutan Sorry, I forgot to name you above on your comment about using `TransformedDistribution`.  That's a good idea but even with 11.1.1.0 `PDF` and `CDF` do not work although `Expectation` does work when using `TransformedDistribution`.