# DistributionChart and kernel smoothing: preventing negative numbers

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, charts, smoothing

I am visualising rather scarce data about size distribution of certain objects (here - oil basin areas on continents, to be specific). There is no raw data, but some already processed quantities, for example, mean and deviation, or typical sizes and numbers of basins and so on. The goal is to reconstruct some fake "smooth" distribution with plausible inference about the function behaviour. Natural tool are kernel smoothing capacities and their implementation, e.g., in violin plots. In Mathematica it is implemented in `DistributionChart[]`. Two extreme examples of fake data, which can be generated from such prerequisites: one is done by sampling a normal distribution, another is just a set of typical sizes ("small" and "big" basins), repeated N times:

```
fakedat = 
 List[RandomVariate[
   NormalDistribution[RandomInteger[{300, 500}], 200], 15], 
  Join[Table[600, 10], Table[100, 6]]]

DistributionChart[fakedat]
```

The result is:

[image: smoothed fake distribution]

But here the values assume negative numbers, both when random sampling a normal distribution (first case), and when processing the positive data during kernel smoothing (second case). How it is possible to imply this natural limitation of non-negative values in the smoothing algorithm? In general case, other such limitations can be considered, for example, in the second data set there can be a threshold value (around 300), delimiting "small" and "big" objects, and it can be desirable to smooth the second set of data taking account this limitation as well.

Comment: Can you make an educated guess at what class of distribution these oil basin areas might follow (might their distribution be analogous to that of some other, known, geological feature?). This might get better answers to this on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). But if you can post some of the processed quantities you mentioned, people will be able to play around with them a bit and give you a more substantial _Mathematica_ answer.

Comment: closely related / possible duplicate Q/A: [DistributionChart range extends beyond the data itself](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/60600/125)

Comment: A guess is that the distribution could have exponential nature exp(-x), or, perhaps, Gamma-like. In any case, negative values are prohibited. This allows to further specify the question. Default behaviour of smoothing kernel algorithms make symmetric Gaussian smoothing (hence the name "violin plot"). How to implement the same or similar smoothing approach to create a highly skewed nonsymmetric distribution? Lets say, gamma x^n exp(-x)?

Comment: Apart from the display problem discussed in kglr's link, do I get it wrong, or why don't you---assuming a given mean and variance---just generate the data with a reasonable non-zero distribution. You mentioned Gamma yourself.

Comment: You might need to customize a figure using the `Bounded` option of `SmoothKernelDistribution`:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/145855/finding-a-distribution-to-fit-truncated-data/145860#145860.

Comment: If the only problem is running the charts out of a specific range (one-sided or two-sided), this can be overcome with the graphical options alone. This will apply for trimming charts >0 (preventing negative numbers) (and possibly <1 or whatever you want). It will not help prevent from extending the distribution out of the range of the original data by SmoothKernelDistribution, as it happens internally in DistributionChart. Just add: `PlotRange->{0,1},PlotRangeClipping->True,PlotRangePadding->0` .